# How to serve a react app to a subdirectory?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using Create React App.

After I type:

```
npm run build
```

It creates a subdirectory called /build. Next I go:

```
serve -s build
```

and it serves my app on: myserver:5000

But I'd like to serve my app on myserver:5000/app1

How is this possible, can I specify a directory on the serve command? And can I deploy multiple apps this way? (for example myserver:5000/app2)

Comment: Create a new folder outside of your workspace to put your built files in (such as `apps` folder). Create subdirectories for your apps (app1, app2.. and so on). Serve the `apps` folder using `serve -s apps` and access your apps using their respective paths in apps folder.

Comment: @tyb unfortunately didn't work... see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120570/create-react-app-build-with-relative-directories